# how can I get a link the exact page if the url is the same as the main page?

Tags: website

It's a bit difficult to explain with words so I will give you an example. please bear with me.

go here
https://www.localharvest.org.au/

wait a bit...

click "list view"

I want to get a link to this list (note that my list is specifically filtered by location and keyword and I want to send someone the link to this list)

This sounds like a dumb question. If I didn't articulate myself clearly I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It's a script, but it can be done.

The format is `https://www.localharvest.org.au/listing-page/?listing_id=1006`

**listing-page** is the actual thing handling the requests and **listing_id** is the id of the specific location.

The ID in my example, if you follow the link, will get you to  Sydney Transition Initiative location.

I used Opera + WebSniffer Extension to determine that.

Re-confirmed to work correctly, using ID 1007 will get you to 'Tamborine Mountain Transition Initiative'.

Comment: that URL opens a page containing a single item from the list. OP asked for the _entire_ list.

Answer (score 0):

Without programming you can't. This URL points to a single page that contains all information. JavaScript is used to show or hide a tab (Filters, Map, List, ...). The page does not seem to have functionality to pass a value in the URL which selects a certain tab after the page opens.

You *can* get the raw data, by requesting https://www.localharvest.org.au/wp-content/plugins/local_harvest/json_all_listings.json (Chrome only, other browsers will complain that it's not valid JSON). But to do something useful with this, you'd need to write your own website.

The five closest locations to a certain point can be requested using this URL (modify lat/lng values to your desire): https://www.localharvest.org.au/wp-content/plugins/local_harvest/fiveclosest.php?lat=-33.867139&lng=151.207114 , but again, it's just data without much layout.

Comment: The location ID can be parsed directly to the URL, see my practical test.

Comment: @Overmind your test does not answer the actual question (i.e. the entire list)

Comment: If the author gives us the location and keyword we can test if there are other various IDs that can apply to that.